# Perform VLOOKUP to the LEFT with an approximate (TRUE, 1) match

Tags: excel, vba

I've got this VBA code that I've used to perform a VLOOKUP to the LEFT (I've found it on MrExcel and edited so that the lookup_value could be any type of data):

---

```
Public Function VLOOKUPLEFT(lookup_value As Variant, table_array As Range, col_index_num As Integer, Optional range_lookup As Boolean = False) As Variant

Dim wk As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim valFind As Range

Set wk = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wk.ActiveSheet

Set valFind = table_array.Find(What:=lookup_value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, -1 * col_index_num)

VLOOKUPLEFT = valFind.Value

End Function
```

---

As you can see, the col_index_num is not referenced anywhere else in the code, because I do not know where to put it exactly.

Apprently, the .Find method does not allow approximate matches. I thought it'd be SearchFormat or LookAt, but the documentation is clear on them, as they regard something totally different:

1. SearchFormat: This indicates whether the value to be searched should be in a specific format (like bold or italics) or not. If the search value should follow a formatting technique, this argument is specified as true, otherwise it is false. The default value of this argument is false.
2. LootAt: This decides whether to match the content of the entire cell (exact match) or to match a part of the cell content (partial match). The constants are xlWhole and xlPart for exact and partial matches respectively. The default value of this argument is xlPart.

Of course, I know I could simply use INDEX/MATCH/MATCH or XLOOKUP. But I wonder if there's a way to implement this, for learning purposes as well.

I've tried to search for a value that would give me an approximate match, but of course it returned the #VALUE! error in Excel. This is because the code does not yet allow for an approximate match.

Comment: 1. `col_index_num` parameter is used to return from the left `col_index_num` column (`.Offset(0, -1 * col_index_num`). The `LEFT` part of the function name wants saying how many columns **to the left** (minus in `Offset`) to return from. 2. `Find` cannot search for a specific part of the string (Left, right). It only searches the whole string or part of it.  `xlWhole` and `xlPart` as you could see in the function definition... You can define your own function using arrays, iterate them and extract matching cases (in another array, in a collection etc.).

Comment: When you say *"the documentation is clear on them"* I would strongly disagree: The `LookAt` argument has no default parameter. The parameter is saved on each call of the method so it is necessary to explicitly set it when it is relevant (in this case it is relevant). The default parameter of the `SearchFormat` argument is `False` although it isn't stated anywhere in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function VLOOKUPLEFT(lookup_value As Variant, table_array As Range, col_index_num As Integer, Optional range_lookup As Boolean = False) As Variant
    
    Dim wk             As Workbook
    Dim ws             As Worksheet
    Dim valFind        As Range
    Dim counter        As Long
    Dim formula_col    As Integer
    
    Set wk = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wk.ActiveSheet
    counter = 0
    
    If range_lookup = TRUE Then
        Do
            Set valFind = table_array.Find(What:=lookup_value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not valFind Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            For i = 1 To table_array.Rows.Count - 1
                If lookup_value >= table_array(i, table_array.Columns.Count).Value And _
                   lookup_value < table_array(i + 1, table_array.Columns.Count).Value Then
                lookup_value = table_array(i, table_array.Columns.Count)
                Set valFind = table_array.Find(What:=lookup_value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                Exit Do
            End If
        Next i
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter >= table_array.Rows.Count Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Else
    Set valFind = table_array.Find(What:=lookup_value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End If

If Not valFind Is Nothing Then
    formula_col = table_array.Columns.Count - col_index_num
    VLOOKUPLEFT = valFind.Offset(0, -1 * formula_col).Value
    'If you want the columns to count from right to left, substitute "-1 * formula_col" with "(-1 * col_index_num) + 1" in the second argument of the .Offset method'
Else
    VLOOKUPLEFT = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Refrain from using it as I need to fix error handling

Comment: Fixed it. You can now use it!

Comment: The function should now work as a regular VLOOKUP, just on the LEFT... I guess...

Comment: Mission complete?